# Selenium IDE not compatible with Firefox 5.0

Tags: selenium-ide, firefox-5

How can I install Selenium IDE on Firefox 5.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenium IDE 1.0.11 is incompatible with Firefox 5.0.

**However**, according to [Selenium IDE release notes](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SeIDEReleaseNotes), Selenium IDE 1.0.12 *will be* compatible with Firefox 5.0.

While Selenium IDE 1.0.12 is not yet formally released, [an early build is available for download](http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users/browse_thread/thread/65d093ebd2fc09b8). (A direct link to the download is provided in the comment thread.)

The link you find there will initiate the automatic Firefox add-on install (after a redirect).